# two collectionView in one page with different data

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

hi I have two collection view in home page how to handle this two collectionView.[image]

how to handle two collectionView in function "NumberIteminSection" and "cellForItemAtIndex" idon't know handle two collectionView in one function?
if have better way please tell me

Comment: Create an `IBOutlet` for each of the `UICollectionView` and `cellForItemAtIndex:` and all other datasource method should have a param `UICollectionView`, so for instance in `numberOfItemsInSection:` do `if collectionView == myFirstCollection { return numberOfItemsInFirstCollection } else //it's mySecondCollectionView return numberOfItemsInSeconCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also handle multiple collection views using tags. You can give different tag value to each Collectionview.

Assign different tag value from storyboard's Attributes inspector field as shown below image.

[image]

And then in delegate or datasource methods you can check the condition like shown below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView.tag == 1{
            return 20
        }else{
            return 10
        }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

As Larme says in his comment, you can write your data source and delegate methods to use an `if` statement to check which collection view is asking for data.

Alternatively, you can create a separate (model) class that acts as the data source/delegate for your collection views, and wire up each collection view to point to a different instance of your model class.